# accessing controller method on button click

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to C# and MVC, while I understand the Controller and the Model side. I have encountered a problem when accessing methods within a controller in order to do a simple conversion that I can then return to my View.

My Controller:

```
public class Exercise05Controller : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Exercise05/

        public ViewResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }


        public ActionResult GramsToOunces(double? grams)
        {
            ViewData["grams"] = grams;
            ViewData["ounces"] = (grams * 0.035d);
            if (grams < 5)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            else if (grams > 5)
            {
                return View("GramsToOunces");
            }
            return RedirectToRoute(new
            {
                controller = "Exercise05",
                action = "Index"
            });
        }
    }
```

My Index View:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>
<form action="/Exercise05/GramsToOunces" method="post">

    <input name="grams" type="text" placeholder="Insert grams to convert to ounces" />

    <input type="submit" value="Convert Grams to Ounces" />
</form>
```

My GramsToOunces View:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}    
<h2>GramsToOunces</h2>
<!-- Currently nothing else here -->
```

I believe my issue is arising somewhere on this line; `action="/Exercise05/GramsToOunces"`. Using debugging has shown me that the the controller processes all the information and gets ready to return the view to suddenly just not return anything. I wish to do a simple conversion and then return this as a view. Would someone be able to point me as to where I am going wrong?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Do you have the view named "GramsToOunces"?

Comment: I do have that as a view, I will update my question accordingly.

Comment: this looks wrong --> `return View("GramsToOunces", "ounces");` Because it looks for a MasterPage/Layout file called `ounces`. Don't you just mean `return View();` which is shorthand for `return View("GramsToOunces");`

Comment: I have corrected my controller, I was indeed incorrect by using `return View("gramsToOunces", "ounces")`

Answer (score 0):

As long as your view is named the same as the controller action, try:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <input name="grams" type="text" placeholder="Insert grams to convert to ounces" />

    <input type="submit" value="Convert Grams to Ounces" />
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just a sanity check, but you are using the line `return View("GramsToOunces", "ounces");`. According to the docs http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470743(v=vs.118).aspx, first string is the view name and second string is the master page. Do you have a master page called "ounces"? If not that could explain why no result is returning. Perhaps you want to use `return View("GramsToOunces");`

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to do the conversion and show the result to user. Just make it Ajaxified. Do not post the entire form.Make an ajax call and get the result and show it to user.

Assuming you have jQuery loaded to your form.

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("GramsToOunce","Exercise5"))
{
    <input name="grams" id="gram" type="text" placeholder="Insert grams" />
    <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" value="Convert Grams to Ounces" />
    <div id="result"></div>
}
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function(){
   $("#btnSubmit").click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      var url=$(this).closest("form").attr("action");
      $.post(url,{ grams : $("#gram").val()} ,function(res){
          $("#result").html(res);
      });
   });
 });
</script>
```

Let's make sure that our action method returns the value.

```
[HttpPost]
public string GramsToOunces(double? grams)
{
   var result=grams * 0.035d;
   return result.ToString();
}
```

Also if you simply want to do the multiplication, just do it in the client side(javascript). No need of a server call.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470743%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) this line:

```
return View("GramsToOunces", "ounces");
```

Tries to return the view with the specified master page. However it seems there is no master page "ounces" in your project. So most likely what you need here is simply:

```
return View("GramsToOunces");
```

Note that you do not need to pass any models whatsoever because you are already using the `ViewData`.